# Toast not working when data is not existing

Tags: android, toast

My `Toast` not working when the data is not existing from Firebase database. What happen ?

```
public void searching(final String id){
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference("Employee");
    Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("id").equalTo(id);
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                if(data.child("id").exists()) {
                    Employee employee = data.getValue(Employee.class);
                    hp.setText(employee.getPhoneNum());
                    address.setText(employee.getAddress());
                    fullName.setText(employee.getFullName());
                    Ic.setText(employee.getIcNum());
                    Sex.setText(employee.getSex());
                    emailVerify.setText(employee.getEmail());

                    getData.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    update.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    fullName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Ic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tAddress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tPhone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    hp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    address.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Sex.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }else{

                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Please Enter Correct Employee ID",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It might be showing some error in logs. please go through htat

Comment: If `dataSnapshot` is empty then `Toast` wont show up. You may need an additional if condition outside `for loop` for checking the `dataSnapshot`  size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be possible your query `databaseReference.orderByChild("id").equalTo(id)` this condition not able to getting any record so it will be not execute for loop so you may to check first the number of children are greater than 0 or not.

***You can try this way Like :***

```
    if (dataSnapshot.dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() > 0){
    for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    if(data.child("id").exists()) {
                        Employee employee = data.getValue(Employee.class);
                        hp.setText(employee.getPhoneNum());
                        address.setText(employee.getAddress());
                        fullName.setText(employee.getFullName());
                        Ic.setText(employee.getIcNum());
                        Sex.setText(employee.getSex());
                        emailVerify.setText(employee.getEmail());

                        getData.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        update.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        fullName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Ic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        tAddress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        tPhone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        hp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        address.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Sex.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }else{

                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Please Enter Correct Employee ID",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }
                  }
                } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"No data found.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
```

Answer (score 1):

When `dataSnapshot.getChildren()` is empty you wont enter in your `for` block so `Toast` wont appear.

Comment: but what if there is not empty but just with the wrong input ?

Comment: btw.. empty text i had handle in somewhere. it is just part of my code which confusing me the Toast is not showing

Comment: @DavidAdam you didn't enter in 'else' block that's why Toast didn't show you could use debug to check this case and find out where you were wrong.